# C++ Adobe Air Overlay

Tags: c++, opengl, air, adobe, hud

Recently i've been investigating possibilities for the creation of the HUD for a game. I found out that Riot Games, for League of Legends, apparently uses Adobe Air for their Heads up Display.

Firstly, how could i go about doing this? I own a copy of Flash professional, so it's more a matter of getting it out of flash, and into the game. I am working with OpenGL in C++.

Secondly, how effective would it be? (Are alpha-blending issues a common problem, or messy edges, etc.)

Comment: Have you ever tested that adobe air client for a few hours xD? You'd think twice about doing it the same way if you had.

Comment: Flash is the animation environment with which i've had the most experience. This is the primary reason i wish to support it. Of course, if it really isn't a wise choice, i'd be happy to learn other methods/environments for animation.

Comment: It could be because I'm old fashioned, but I like to limit the number of languages/tools I use for one application to a minimum. I don't think anything good can come of using more. This is only my humble philosophy though, don't let it stop you from trying to create an awesome application the way you want ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Adobe Flash Professional tool, you also require a special version of the Flash Player, namely a library you can embed into your own program/game to integrate it with the rest of the graphics system. You can get this only using an extra license.

Also given the reoccuring performance issues of Flash it might not be the wisest decision, although for creating nice animated UIs its a productive environment.

Answer (score 0):

Games such as Assassin's Creed use something called [Scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform) to make UI with Flash. That's what League of Legends is probably using too.

It's been used on lots of AAA games.